# How to hot deploy android project?

Tags: android, deployment, installation

Each time I changed a snippet of code, I have to compile the whole project and reinstall it on my phone . Is there any way to only deploy the increment part of code? Now my apk is larger than 15 megabytes, redeploying takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio has now an [Instant Run](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html#instant-run) feature.

Comment: Freeline would be much better choice which compile and redeploy within seconds.

Comment: JRebel is also good choice that I use now, which supports the latest gradle build version.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but you can have a look at [this](http://jimulabs.com/beta/)

Comment: This is good, but it can only hot deploy UI changes.Thanks anyway.How I wish it could hot deploy source code changes.

Answer (score 0):

I find JRebel + MuMu emulator a very good combo for improving efficiency, which saved me a lot of time.